# bootstrap and font awesome need to be embed into an email campaign

Tags: embed, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

need your help.

I've created a html file for an email campaign.

My  section looks like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Mono|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e62601324.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
h1 {font-size: 18px;}
.logo img {width: 100px; margin-top: 5%;}
.left-section {margin-top: 2%;}
.right-section {border-left: 1px solid #62a70f;}
.main-content {font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
h1 {background-color: #004467; padding: 10px; color: #fff;}
.right-section {transform: translateY(10%);}
.left-section li, .right-section li {list-style-type: none;}
.fa {color: #62a70f;}
ul {margin-left: -40px;}
footer {border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 10px; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5%;}
</style>
</head>
```

The problem is that the email server does not use the bootstrap and the font awesome, my colleagues told me to use them embedded and I don't  know how to do that.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Many thanks,

Sandra P.

Comment: This thing won't be easy. Every email client renders things a bit differently, and web fonts and external styles (modern web technology) won't work properly in almost any email client.